# JQuery Promise question

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on a project which uses many ajax requests to access data from restfull services. Some operations require multiple sequential calls. As soon as i implemented the first of these i ran into race conditions. (calling ajaxCall_1, then ajaxCall_2, which uses the result of ajaxCall_1, but ajaxCall_1 had not returned yet). Of course I could use the .success property, but that does not do the trick for me. Let me explain with a simplified example below. I've got a .js file containing:

```
function getServerBoolean(){
    $.get('url_1',function(data){return data)});
}

function refreshWidget(){
    $.get('url_2',function(data){
        var serverBoolean = getServerBoolean(); 
        --do some html building here based on boolean returned from server-- }
    );
}

function setServerValue(newValue){
   $.post('url',{key:newValue},function(data){
      // server model has changed, so refresh widget. 
      refreshWidget();
   });

}
```

Whenever I call setServerValeu('someValue'), the widget needs to refresh itself, but before doing this it needs to know the server boolean value. In this fashion I have many more siutations, so simply giving a callback as a method argument and then calling it in .success() does not do the trick for me.

I stumbled upon the $.when  $.then  $.done methods, but am not sure how to use these for my situation. Is there anybody who might be able to help me how to set this up?

Thanks in advance!

Richard

Comment: Why can't you use .success() to call a function that contains ajaxCall_2?

Comment: I've got an api which contains many rest/ajax calls to the server. If I were to use callbacks with these methods I would end up with many nested calls with callbacks, this is not what I want due to maintenance of the code. Next to that I would have to change all methods to allow callback functions as parameters, this is also not what i want, I want to keep the api as clean as possible. $.when().then does this perfectly. (And it works like a charm for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about $.when $then $done, but functional way of doing this would be to pass callbacks around. It could look like that:

```
function getServerBoolean(dataCallback){
    $.get('url_1', dataCallback);
}

function refreshWidget(){
    $.get('url_2',function(data){
        getServerBoolean(function(boolValueReturned) {
           //do something with the value
        });
    });
}
```

Of course there could be numerous way to tweak this, like for example checking (in getServerBoolean) if the argument we got is a function and if not set it to some default callback.

Comment: This sounds good. I'll give this a try. I'm a bit afraid this (in my case) will eventually end up in a lot of nested methods/callbacks. i was hoping the $.when().then approach would avoid that from happening..

Comment: Well it's the cleanest approach anyway. I checked $.when description in jQuery documentation and basically its similiar thing - you pass the callbacks that gets executed after some other callback is done. The code shouldn't be too complicated if most (if not all) of the callbacks would be defined as named functions, and then you would just have to define "flows" or functions that would pass those named callback functions in desired order.

Comment: The term named function... Is that assigning a function to a var? And then using the .call() method?

Comment: Assigning a function to a var or making it an attribute of some object. Basically anything that will enable you tu refer to that function by name :)